# Trying to define the inverse function of the cartesian product

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This question must have been asked before but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Defining a mapping from two sets to the set of their Cartesian product seems seems pretty easy, unless I'm completely wrong:

$$f(A,B) = \{(a,b) \mid a∈A, b∈B\}$$

My question is - how do I define the inverse function?  I want to define a function that takes a set of ordered pairs and returns the original sets. The process is clear to me, but I find it hard writing it mathematically.

Also what is a little unclear to me is the idea of inverting a pairing function: it takes two parameters and return one, so when you invert it you have two solutions from one parameter. How is it not a problem?

Hope I was clear, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Firstly, one must be quite careful in talking about functions whose inputs could range over all sets; I am not an expert in set theory by any means, but I believe we still can refer to functions between [proper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29) (of which the collection of all sets is an example). Letting $\mathsf{Set}$ denote the class of all sets (in fact it can be given the extra structure of a [category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_%28mathematics%29), though that doesn't really concern us here, I suppose), we can define the "Cartesian product" function (or rather, [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor), if we want to use categories*), $P:\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{Set}$ by
$$\text{for any }(A,B)\in\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set},\quad P(A,B)=A\times B$$

and this is the function you are talking about, but  certainly *any set $X$, not all of whose elements are ordered pairs, will not be in the image of $P$*, and therefore there is no inverse function $Q:\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$ such that $Q(P(A,B))=(A,B)$ for all $(A,B)\in\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$, because it makes no sense to talk about "the original sets" of the sets $X=\{5,\pi\}$ or $Y=\{\mathbb{Z}\}$, for example, so we cannot define $Q(X)$ or $Q(Y)$.

*talking about a functor would also require defining $P$ on functions; we would do so by 
$$\text{for any }(f,g)\in\text{Hom}_{\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}}((A,B),(C,D)),\qquad  P(f,g)=A\times B\;\;\xrightarrow{\;\;f\times g\;\;}\;\; C\times D$$

Comment: It wasn't two clear but It won't work. I am trying to show that the correspondence between (AXB)XC and AXBXC is one to one and onto. I thought maybe I could find an inverse function. So, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The best way to show something is one-to-one and onto is to construct an inverse. Show that, for any three sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, the functions
$$f:(A\times B)\times C\to A\times B\times C$$
$$g:A\times B\times C\to (A\times B)\times C$$
defined by
$$f\big(((a,b),c)\big)=(a,b,c)\qquad g\big((a,b,c)\big)=((a,b),c)$$
are inverse to each other.

Comment: You can also ask your real question, about $A\times B\times C$ and $(A\times B)\times C$, in a separate post.